# Coordinate ring of a disjoint union of two points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to solve Exercise 11.2.4 from Shafarevich:

“Suppose that X consists of two points. Prove that the coordinate ring $k[X]$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of two copies of the field $k$.”

**My attempt**
Let $X = \left\{ p_1, p_2 \right\}$ and $X_i= \left\{ p_i \right\}$ for $i=1,2$.  I know that $k[X_i] = k$. Now, if $f \in k[X_1] \oplus k[X_2]$, it is true that $f= f_1 + f_2$ with $f_i$ regular on $X_i$. Therefore, $f \in k[X_1 \cup X_2]$. I have now problems proving that $k[X_1 \cup X_2] \subseteq k[X_1] \oplus k[X_2]$. Any help?

Comment: $X_i$ form an open covering of $X$ so any regular function is determined by restrictions to $X_i$

Comment: So $f$ is the sum of the two restrictions, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have already solved this. Still I will post a solution for other people.

Let $X=\{a,b\} \subset \mathbb{A}^n$. Then $I(X)\subset I(\{a\}), I(X)\subset I(\{b\}),$
where both $m_1=I(\{a\}),m_2=I(\{b\})$ are maximal ideals.

$X=V(J)$, say. Then $I(X)=\sqrt{J}$. Now $J\subset P$, where $P$ is a prime ideal implies $V(P) \subset X.$ Since $V(P)$ is irreducible, $V(P)$ is singleton. Thus $P=m_1 \text{ or }m_2.$ Thus $\sqrt{J}=m_1 \cap m_2=m_1m_2.$ $k[X]=\frac{k[t]}{(t-a)(t-b)} \cong k \oplus k,$ by Chinese remainder theorem.

**Remark:** Instead of two points, we can take $X$ any finite set, and with the same method follows the following: $$|X|=n \Rightarrow k[X] \cong \underbrace{k \oplus k \oplus \dots \oplus k}_{n \text{ times}}.$$